# readinessProbe use DNS instead of IP Address for Host

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, redis

I currently configure my Nginx Pod **readinessProbe** to monitor Redis port 6379, and I configure my redis-pod behind the redis-service (ClusterIP).

So my idea is **to monitor Redis port though redis-service using DNS** instead of IP address.

When I use `readinessProbe.host: redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local` the Nginx-pod is not running. When I describe the Nginx-pod `$ kubectl describe pods nginx`,  I found below error in Events section:

`Readiness probe failed: dial tcp: lookup redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local: no such host`

It only works if I use ClusterIP instead of DNS.

Please help me figure out how to use DNS instead of ClusterIP.

My Pod file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 80
    readinessProbe:
      tcpSocket:
        host: redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local
        port: 6379
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it usually makes sense to probe other services like this.  Say we have a hypothetical very slow Nginx that takes a minute to start up; do you want to claim it's "ready" because the Redis backing store is up?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, i need to make sure Redis is running and able to accept packet first before i let user to access the Nginx. May i know what is your recommended way?

Comment: I agree with @DavidMaze that this seems like a bit of an odd approach to probe redis directly - especially since this doesn't *actually* test the nginx service. Is it possible for you to probe redis *through* nginx instead? e.g. if nginx is supposed to route requests on `/redis-endpoint` to `redis-service`, then just set the nginx readiness probe to get `/redis-endpoint`. That way you get to test both simultaneously, and don't have to worry about DNS/IP for redis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

Instead of using tcpSocket, just use exec.
Exec your tcpCheck script inside the container to check the service:port availability.

**Use your init-container to share the script with the main container.**

Thanks.